# PHP MYSQL Update Query not working No ERRORS

Tags: php, mysql

```
        $cod = $_POST['cod'];
        $nume = $_POST['nume'];
        $prenume = $_POST['prenume'];
        $institutie = $_POST['institutie'];

        $introduceredate = "UPDATE concurenti SET nume = $nume, prenume = $prenume, institutie = $institutie WHERE cod = $cod";
        $querydate = mysqli_query($db, $introduceredate);
        if(!querydate)
        {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db));
            exit();
        }
        header("Refresh:0");
```

There is no errors in error log, or on the page, nothing, i can't figure it out. Nothing gets send trough database.

Comment: See about prepared statements and the perils of sql injection. If you address that, your other problems will magically disappear

Comment: Your sql values should be enclosed in single quotes. Or better, use prepared statements so you avert sql injections as well.

Comment: Let me try that, didn't think of that, dunno why, thank you very much, let's see now :D

Comment: Worked like a charm, I am so dumb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters inside the query need to be inside single quotes. E.g '$prenume'.

You should look at prepared statements too, this will help you avoid any SQL injection attacks. If you don't want to go down that route, you need to sanitize your post values.

Comment: I didn't bother with sanitizing the post values or using prepared statements cuz this system will be used just by me and a friend of mine, usually I do that, BUT HOW THE HECK I FORGOT ABOUT SINGLE QUOTES :))))))

Comment: Is you site being hosted on a live web server?